# Computer Vision: Path for playing video

Tags: matlab, video, computer-vision

I want to use video from following directory
`'E:\Multimedia Security\matlab\UCSD_Anomaly_Dataset.v1p2\UCSDped1\Train\Train001'`

Following is the code which i wrote

```
close all
clear all
clc

workingDir = 'E:\Multimedia 
Security\matlab\UCSD_Anomaly_Dataset.v1p2\UCSDped1\Train\Train001';

videoofReader = vision.VideoFileReader(dir(fullfile(workingDir, 'abc.avi')));
videoPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer;

while ~isDone(videoofReader)
  frame = step(videoofReader);
  step(videoPlayer, frame);
end

release(videoofReader);
release(videoPlayer);
```

Error which i get is

```
`Error using VideoFileReader.set.Filename (line 139)
Expected Filename to be one of these types:

char

Instead its type was struct.

Error in C:\Program
Files\MATLAB\R2012a\toolbox\matlab\system\+matlab\+system\setProp.p>setProp 
(line 14)


Error in
```

C:\ProgramFiles\MATLAB\R2012a\toolbox\matlab\system+matlab+system\SystemProp.p>SystemProp.set (line
373)

Error in C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\toolbox\matlab\system+matlab+system\SystemProp.p>SystemProp.parseInputs
(line 635)

Error in C:\Program
Files\MATLAB\R2012a\toolbox\matlab\system+matlab+system\SystemProp.p>SystemProp.setProperties
(line 138)

Error in C:\Program
Files\MATLAB\R2012a\toolbox\vision\vision+vision\VideoFileReader.p>VideoFileReader.VideoFileReader
(line 131)

Error in kl2 (line 18)
  videoofReader = vision.VideoFileReader(dir(fullfile(workingDir, 'abc.avi')));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System prompts `you Error in kl2 (line 18)` so this line has a problem. You do not need to use `dir` because you already have an absolute path.

Give you two solutions:

1. `videoofReader = vision.VideoFileReader(fullfile(workingDir, 'abc.avi'));`
2. `dirstruct = dir(fullfile(workingDir, 'abc.avi'));
   videoofReader = vision.VideoFileReader(dirstruct{1});`